# Non meager union of lines

Tags: set-theory

Suppose every subset of real line of size $\aleph_1$ is meager. Can we conclude that any union of $\aleph_1$ lines in plane is also meager? If we replace meager by null, this was negatively answered by Shelah and Steprans in Comparing the uniformity invariants of null sets for different measures. Adv. Math.,
192(2), 403–426, 2005. I don't know if people have looked at the category analogue